# Как заполнить БД MS Access с помощью LINQ? (link2db)

Tags: c#, база-данных, linq, insert, linq2sql

В поисках инструмента для работы с БД при помощи LINQ наткнулся на linq2db, но толи я тупой, толи документация слишком скудная, но я застрял на элементарном Insert.
Ссылка на github библиотеки: https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db

Вот моя Таблица в БД:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[Table(Name = "AnimePosters")]
public class AnimePoster
{
    [PrimaryKey, Column(Name = "title_id"), NotNull]
    public int title_id { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "original"), NotNull]
    public string original { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "preview"), NotNull]
    public string preview { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "x96"), NotNull]
    public string x96 { get; set; }

    [Column(Name = "x48"), NotNull]
    public string x48 { get; set; }
}

public class DBRatesDB : LinqToDB.Data.DataConnection
{
    public DBRatesDB() : base("RatesDB") { }

    public ITable<AnimePoster> AnimePoster { get { return GetTable<AnimePoster>(); } }
}
```

Описал сущности для таблицы. На считывание (Select) компилятор не ругается, а вот, когда я пытаюсь воспользоваться Insert как написано в ReadMe.

Пример из README.md

```
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
  db.Insert(product);
}
```

Как я понял, **product** это экземпляр класса сущности, которая определяет таблицу из БД, то есть для меня это должен быть AnimePoster, но выдаёт непонятную мне ошибку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто может помочь с этим или у вас есть свои варианты библиотек для работы с LINQ с БД Access или SQLite (любой из них).
Буду очень благодарен, если к своим вариантам приложите примеры для основных запросов вроде Select|Insert|Delete|Update или ссылку на документацию, где это всё подробно расписано.

Comment: А вы именно вот этот nuget пакет ставили `linq2db.Access` ?

Comment: @Bulson, устанавливал вот так: `PM> Install-Package linq2db`

Comment: А надо бы так [устанавливать](https://www.nuget.org/packages/linq2db.Access/)

Comment: @Bulson, а в чём разница? Разве мой вариант не включает в себя уже Access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Документация библиотеки достаточно не плохая. Библиотека для обеспечения безопасности типов и выявления ошибок на этапе компиляции использует деревья выражений [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

В первую очередь это позволяет Вам избавиться от "магических строк" для имен объектов базы данных и предоставляет простой C# синтаксис для генерации запросов к БД.

Конкретно в Вашем примере у Вас ошибка в использовании (и да, в документации это есть). И Да `Insert` в данном случае это команда которой нужно указать что вставлять не много по другому:

```
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
  AnimePoster ap = new AnimePoster(); // get animePoster
  db.AnimePoster
    .Value(p => p.original, () => ap.original)
    .Value(p => p.preview, () => ap.preview)
    .Value(p => p.x48, () => ap.x48)
    .Value(p => p.x96, () => ap.x96)
    .Value(p => p.title_id, () => ap.title_id)
    .Insert();
}
```

Как верно заметил @Bulson более простым способом (если вам не нужно выбирать какие поля вставлять, а какие нет) будет просто:

```
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
  AnimePoster ap = new AnimePoster(); // get animePoster

  db.Insert(ap); // Вместо db.AnimePoster.Insert(ap);
}
```

Или с `Identity`:

```
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
  AnimePoster ap = new AnimePoster(); // get animePoster

  db.InsertWithIdentity(ap);
}
```

Собственно под заголовком Insert там есть и более сложные и гибкие примеры и более простые. В том коде что у вас вы также можете вставить сразу несколько элементов в БД:

```
using (var db = new DbNorthwind())
{
  var animePosters = db.AnimePoster.Select( /*Ваш Select*/x => x);

  db.BulkCopy(animePosters);
}
```

Comment: Чего-то я не понял, вот это что ли ошибочно: `db.Insert(product);` ?

Comment: @Bulson, нет, не ошибочно.

Comment: @Bulson, обновил ответ, спасибо. Сразу не захотел привести просто `.Insert` из-за того что это не Identity-вставка.

Comment: `db.InsertWithIdentity(ap);` по документации должен отдавать айдишник только что добавленного элемента, как я понял из документации.

Comment: @Bulson, да `InsertWithIdentity` возвращает айдишник только что добавленного элемента. Или Вы также хотите сказать что это просто потенциальный `id` следующего элемента, который ещё не вставлен в БД?

Comment: Нет, все ОК. Я просто решил уточнить, т.к. вы в своем примере не использовали возвращаемое значение. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Получается при использовании db.Insert(product), он сам поймет к какой таблице нужно добавить строчку? Просто в БД одна таблица на время теста, далее их будет больше.

Comment: @Mr.Modest, не совсем. Сам он ничего не поймет. Просто в данном примере указание таблицы происходит не явно. Что бы это сделать явно можно писать: `db.Insert<AnimePoster>(animePoster)`. Но в C# это необязательно, потому что обобщенный тип(`<AnimePoster>`) можно вывести зная тип параметра (`animePoster`). Или же можно также явно указать название таблицы строкой так: `db.Insert(product, "AnimePoster");`